# What is the use case for default argument without name in the function signature

Tags: c++, c++11, default-arguments, function-signature

Taken from cpp reference, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments

`void f(int, int = 7); // #2 OK: adds a default`

Is there any particular use case where this is useful, considering there is no name to the default argument.

Or I am just reading too much between the lines and should just leave with the understanding that it is just the function signature declaration and in function definition one has to provide the variable name to make any use of the second parameter in the function.

I was expecting the variable name in the function signature.

Comment: Why there's no need to name the other parameters in a function signature?

Comment: It is called Declaration.....!!!

Comment: So basically it is just to declare the function and in definition one will provide the name to the parameter to make it useful.

Comment: *"Or I am just reading too much between the lines and should just leave with the understanding that it is just the function signature declaration and in function definition one has to provide the variable name to make any use of the second parameter in the function."* - correct.

Comment: There's nothing specific to default argument values here. The question and its answer apply exactly the same to arguments without default values.

Comment: lambda is overkill is above example, but might be useful for more complex initialization... dedicated function might make thing clearer though.

Comment: It is a good idea to name the parameters in the declaration, as it helps the human reader. The compiler doesn't care though.

Comment: If you have another question, make a new post, don't edit the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void f(int, int);` is a function ***declaration***, which is different of function ***definition***.

In the declaration, we (the compiler) only need to know that we declare a function `f` that takes 2 `int`s and returns a `void`.

The names of the parameters are not necessary here since we do not refer to them.

But in the ***definition***, it's another story. In that case, we need to specify parameters names in order to be able to use them.

For example:

```
// Declaration
void f(int, int);

// Definition
void f(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << a << ',' << b << '\n';
}
```

In the above example, we could not use the `a` and `b` in the function definition if we did not give them those names. But in the declaration, we didn't care.

**Note:** It may still be useful to specify names in the declaration for documentation purposes (or simply to help the human reader).

**Note 2:** Actually you can also omit the parameter name in the definition, but in that case, you won't be able to refer to it.
It is sometimes used when we plan to define the function body later and do not want to have a "unused parameter" warning while compiling (Although I personally prefer to keep and comment out the parameter name instead).

Comment: Your "Note" makes it seem like an afterthought. It would be _pretty stupid_ and generally pointless to not to include the names in the declaration aswell. I've rarely seen them not. Your answer should be "Please include them" and _then_ say why you can skip them, rather than the other way round.

Comment: @MikeVine Yes, I added the note afterwards. It's to make it clear that the point of the answer was to explain why it is not necessary to include the names in the declaration. I wanted to make it clear that while it's not necessary, it's still useful for other reasons (maintainability, documentation, etc...).

Comment: It is possible to have an unnamed argument in the function *definition*, if the argument is not used (but is, say, a placeholder for an argument that will be used in a future update of the function).   Most compilers (can be configured to) issue a warning if a named argument is unused in a function block and leaving the argument unnamed is one approach to deliberately suppress that warning.

Comment: @Peter Yes I know that, but I didn't consider mentioning it because it was not the OP's point. But I will add it for completeness.

Comment: @Fareanor   No problem.    I commented in interests of completeness, not to suggest you didn't know.

Answer (score 3):

Parameter names are not mandatory in function declarations nor in function definitions.

```
void f(int, int = 7);

int main()
{
    f(1);
    return 0;
}

void f(int, int)
{
    return;
}
```

Compiles without errors...

However, if you want to make use of the parameters then you must give them names in order to be able to reference them.

With function declarations, you do not reference the parameters but giving them names is useful for you and readers of your code; the compiler doesn't care.

In function definitions is where you reference the parameters, so here is where you have to provide them with names:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int, int = 7);

int main()
{
    f(1);
    return 0;
}

void f(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

Output: 7

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out the argument name in the function declaration. The compiler just needs to know that the function takes two `int`s and that one has a default value. If the argument is needed in the *definition* then a name needs to be provided.
But, there are use cases where you might even leave out the argument in the definition.

Maybe a bit contrived, but one example could be a function that used to only take one argument and can now take two, but you want to keep old code compiling and the second argument is optional and use of the second argument has not yet been implemented. In that case you might start by adding the second argument to the function signature with some reasonable default and people can now start calling the function with two arguments as well as just one as usual and then in the future you expand your implementation to actually make use of (and thus name) the second argument in the function *definition*.